# InternalServerError;TypeLoadException:Method''in type''from assembly '',version=''...implementation

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, crud

TypeLoadException: Method 'get_QueryProvider' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalDatabaseFacadeDependencies' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.
While I used to code this paragraph:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using apiGestor.Models;
namespace apiGestor.Context
{
    public class AppDbContext :DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options): base(options){}
        public DbSet<Gestores_Bd> FolsBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I try to connect my CDUD with SQLSERVER AND SHOW ONLY HIS DATA OF A TABLE BY A DATABASE

Comment: What's the version of .net core your current Proj running on ? And what's your version  ofMicrosoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational  ?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in my unit test when my project is using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 6.0.21` but my unit test is using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory 7.0.0`